# .NET change searched locations web views in MVC4

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm a newbie in web language.
I started a .NET project on my visual studio 2010, it's in MVC 4 and razor structure.

The problem is that i had an folder in the views folder, with a view in it, but when i try to access the view i got this error:

```
The view 'searchWeb' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Home/searchWeb.aspx
~/Views/Home/searchWeb.ascx
~/Views/Shared/searchWeb.aspx
~/Views/Shared/searchWeb.ascx
~/Views/Home/searchWeb.cshtml
~/Views/Home/searchWeb.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/searchWeb.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/searchWeb.vbhtml
```

I guess he is not searching in the right folder...but how to change this ?
I looked some topics and apparently i have to make a new viewEngine and inherirted from the old one ?
Is it possible to fix it without making a new view engine ? or can you show me how to make the new view engine ? thank you !

EDIT:

this is my homeController.cs:

```
namespace Searcher.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult homeWeb()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Searching for sites over the web.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult homeImages()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Searching for images over the web.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult homeVideos()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Searching for videos over the web.";

            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult searchWeb()
        {
            // do something with the search value
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my homeWeb, which is calling the searchWeb:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search Web";
}
@section featured {
    <section class="featured">
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <hgroup class="title">
                <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
                <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
            </hgroup>
        </div>
    </section>
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("searchWeb", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "searchForm" }))    
{ 
    <div class="main-block">
        <p>
            <div>
                <input size="200px" type="text" name="searchValue" />
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
            </div>
        </p>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So where is your searchWeb.cshtml file?
Your controller is telling the view engine to look for the search.Web.cshtml file in the Home controller, which normally translates to
~/View/Home/searchWeb.cshtml (one of the default search locations you mentioned in your question).

Comment: i have an other folder named Search, but no search controller, is that my mistake ?

Comment: The convention at work here is that {Name}Controller maps to Views/{Name}/ folder. You can specify the full path of the .cshtml file if you don't want to follow the convention `return View("~/Views/Search/filename.cshtml")`

Comment: okay thanks i will try the return the full path to see if its working

Answer (score 0):

Its not recomended to change view search location. Trust me:). Especially for newbie in MVC.
And you dont need to change it, this must working from the box. 
So make shure that the view location is right. As i can see for this view you need create the action
in Home Controller like

```
    public ActionResult searchWeb()
    {            
        return View();
    }
```

or you trying to call thi view as partial?

Comment: im sure you doing something wrong with your views=). Try do delete all views and then right click on each action method in controller(in VS) and in popup menu click "Add View" button. view should be created automaticaly for action